# Optimization of a for loop with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, optimization

This is a problem that I found recently and I enjoy very much to design a solution. I think that it is a nice exercise and a good example of the combination of *for loops* and pandas.

I have the following pandas data frame, with three columns: **['runs','Period_change', 'Close', 'sum']**.

[image]

I want to implement an alternative to the following *for* loop to speed up the program.

```
import pandas as pd

game = pd.read_csv('test.csv').set_index('timestamp').dropna()
for l in game['runs'].unique():
    game['sum'][game['runs'] == l] = game[game['runs'] == l]['Period_change'].sum()/game[game['runs'] == l]['Close'].iloc[0]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, your for loop can be replace by `groupby`

```
df['sum']=df.name.map(df.groupby('name').apply(lambda x : x['Period_change'].sum()/x['Close'].iloc[0]))
```